# Event not firing on model created Laravel.5.6

Tags: laravel, events, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to fire an event on company created model. everything is fine in my check. but I don't know I am mistaking. the event is not firing at all.

Here is my Code.

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\NewCompany' => [
        'App\Listeners\SendWelcomeCompany',
    ],
];
```

Event
**NewCompany.php**

```
namespace App\Events;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\Company;

class NewCompany
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

   public $company;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Company $company)
{
    $this->company = $company;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
}
}
```

Listener
**SendWelcomeCompany.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\NewCompany;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendWelcomeCompany
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  NewCompany  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(NewCompany $event)
    {
        Mail::to($event->company->email)->send(new NewCompanyWelcome($event->company));
    }
}
```

Company Model
**Company.php**

```
namespace App;

use App\Events\NewCompany;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

protected $events = [
        'created' => NewCompany::class,
    ];
```

Please tell me what is it I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: It should `protected $dispatchesEvents` instead of `protected $events`, isn't it? On your Company Model

Comment: Thank you, man. it worked, the event is firing now